# android:How to delete a ListView item with checkbox?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, checkbox

I am a beginner level android developer and was working on creating a  basic To-Do list app. The app contains custom listview with a coloured circle to show priority, the title and a checkbox to check and delete the item when the user has done it. The app stores these to-dos using SQLite database and uses Loader to retrieve data.

What I'm trying is to delete the item from the list as soon as the checkbox is checked.

I tried to implement deletion task in the Adapter class like this (Also tried to animate deletion.):

```
CheckBox itemCheck = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.todo_checked);
    itemCheck.setChecked(false);
    itemCheck.setTag(priority);
    itemCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoTable.ID);
                final int id = cursor.getInt(idIndex);
                final Uri uriTodDelete = ContentUris.withAppendedId(TodoTable.TABLE_URI,id);
                Animation slideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
                slideOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        context.getContentResolver().delete(uriTodDelete,null,null);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                view.startAnimation(slideOut);
```

The problem is, whenever I delete the top item of the listview, the item just below it gets deleted. But it works fine if I delete from the bottom.

How do I fix this? Any help will be appreciated.

P.S the delete method of the Content Resolver class is handling notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: Please post your Adapter code to help others diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**A wild guess**, you are not moving the cursor to the relevant row
so cursor is on pos x but you may click -on listview- on item at pos y.

so you need to move cursor to the relevant position before you try to get the ID value.

i assume you are doing this code in `getView()` ? as you are usign an adapter.

You need to make use of position parameter passed in `getView()` as below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    :
    :
    if(isChecked){
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoTable.ID);
        final int id = cursor.getInt(idIndex);
        :
        :
    }

    :
    :
}
```

you also need to make sure the cursor is being `re query` otherwise you may get some problems with positions once you remove items from list
-- i think this is auto handled if you are using a `cursor adapter`?
just double check on that.